# CLion: run/debug binary on chroot'ed environment

Tags: linux, clion, chroot

I have an SDK that has its own full linux environment, and provides the `sdkroot` command to run things inside its environment (its probably a glorified chroot). For running a binary like `my_great_bin` I do `sdkroot my_great_bin` on the terminal.

Now, I have a CMake project on CLion that correctly builds the binary using the sdk environment (using the cmake, gcc, etc from the sdk).

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to run the binary from CLion within the SDK's environment, like I do manually on the terminal. Trying to run it in CLion will simply execute the binary on my machine's environment (`./my_great_bin` instead of `sdkroot my_great_bin`).

EDIT: one workaround I've found is to create a run configuration where the Executable is "sdkroot" and the Program arguments are "./my_great_bin", but debugging does not work.